# New-ScheduledTaskAction : The term 'New-ScheduledTaskAction' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

My script is like-

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "BolusDemoDataGenerator.BAT"
$TaskStartTime = [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(2) 
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $TaskStartTime -Once

$setting = New-ScheduledTaskSettingSet
$inputTask = -action $action  -trigger $trigger -settings
Register-ScheduledTask BatchRunTask -InputObject $inputTask
```

but I am getting an error

```
New-ScheduledTaskAction : The term 'New-ScheduledTaskAction' is not 
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At C:\Users\abc\Desktop\hi.ps1:1 char:11
+ $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "BolusDemoDataGenerator.BAT"
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-ScheduledTaskAction:String) 
[], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Not sure what is wrong I tried to execute this powershell script to create a task in task scheduler to execute a bat file present in desktop

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using as the cmdlet only became available in PowerShell 4.0.  You can determine the version using     `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

Comment: it says Mazor 4      minor 0   Build -1  Revision-1

Comment: In that case try importing the module     `Import-Module ScheduledTasks`

Comment: [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649817%28v=wps.630%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Says this only applies to Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1. Is your OS any of that?

Comment: @RohinSidharth `Other Versions` will show it's also there for Server 2012/Windows 8 and Windows 10/Server 2016.

Comment: On which OS are you working ? Can you give `$PSVersionTable` ?

Comment: PS C:\Users\abc> $PSVersionTable

Name                                        Value
----                                               -----
PSVersion                                   4.0
WSManStackVersion                  3.0
SerializationVersion                    1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                                4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                               6.3.9600.18728
PSCompatibleVersions              {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With **PowerShell 4.0** a scheduled task can be easily created with the new cmdlets `New-ScheduledTaskAction`, `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` and `Register-ScheduledTask`, but unfortunately it's not possible in the prévious versions (have a look to `PSVersion` in `$PSVersionTable`).

For previous version you can find many examples where people invoke the `schtasks.exe` command.

If you want to avoid calling external executables and do as much in PowerShell as possible you can use the [Task Scheduler’s com object for creating a scheduled task](https://www.verboon.info/2013/12/powershell-creating-scheduled-tasks-with-powershell-version-3/).

```
# Open the Task Scheduler com object
$service = new-object -ComObject("Schedule.Service")
```

Comment: I am using Powershell 4.0